# AWS-SDK-CPP Error C1083 : Cannot Open Include File: 'aws/core/utils/logging/LogLevel.h'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, unreal-engine5, aws-sdk-cpp

I am trying to integrate AWS-SDK-CPP into Unreal Engine 5.1 but I keep getting this error:
`Error C1083 : Cannot Open Include File: 'aws/core/utils/logging/LogLevel.h'`

What I did was I used this snippet of code:

```
#include "AWSSDK/Public/core/Aws.h"
#include "AWSSDK/Public/core/utils/logging/LogLevel.h"

...

const Aws::SDKOptions Options;
Options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace;
InitAPI(Options);
ShutdownAPI(Options);
```

I can include and use `"AWSSDK/Public/core/utils/logging/LogLevel.h"` without any issue but Aws.h@line 7 itself seems to not able to include the file.

[Folder Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b6Ry.png)

The image above shows my folder hierarchy which the includes in the `Public\core` folder and the .lib files in the `lib` folder.

The modules I selected are: Core and Cognito-idp
CMake version : 3.21.7
Unreal Engine version: 5.1

What I tried:

- I tried to build the using vcpkg and build the source for AWS repo directly but both methods still give me the same error.

What expected to happen:

- Given vcpkg has the easiest build and install procedures, the library should work when I move them into Unreal Engine.

What actually happened:

- This error happened `Aws.h(7): Error C1083 : Cannot open include file: 'aws/core/utils/logging/LogLevel.h': No such file or directory`

What can I do to solve this issue? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.